# Unable to invoke derived class function in C++

Tags: c++

I'm sure I missed some part of the code.

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Record
{
private:
    int age;
    string name;
public:
    virtual int getType()=0;
};


class Student:  public Record
{
  private:
     int level_;
  public:
     Student()
     {
        level_=1;
     };
     ~Student() {};
     int getType()
     {
        return 1;
     }

     int level()
     {
        return level_;
     }
};


int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
  Record *r = new Student();
  cout <<"tuype " << r->getType();
  cout <<"Class " << r->level();
}
```

Question is : Why am I not able to invoke `r->level()`?. What changes are required to get it invoked?

Comment: Your `Record` class should have a virtual destructor. Your `Student` class should have an implicitly-defined one. And none of your functions need semicolons after the bodies.

Comment: I think it's generally not a good idea to have a method `getType()`. It is not always a bad thing, but try to avoid it if possible. And don't forget about virtual destructor in classes designed for inheritance, it is very important

Comment: @chris: +1 for the virtual destructor advice, but it doesn't matter whether `Student` has an implicitly defined destructor.  Semicolons, *shiver* ;-).

Comment: @TonyD, Doesn't here, but putting one in yourself only gives you disadvantages when you get into the stuff where it makes a difference.

Comment: @chris: could you explain? - I'm curious what you have in mind....

Comment: what do you want to acchieve with the `getType()` method? if it is only there to distinguish between different sub-classes of `Record` use `dynamic_cast` instead

Comment: @TonyD, For starters, both literal types and trivially copyable types require a trivial destructor, which requires it not be user-provided. One thing that relies on this is that `constexpr` can be applied to the declaration of a static data member of a literal type. I can never remember what all ultimately has a trivial destructor requirement, but that's a start.

Comment: @chris: thanks for explaining where you were coming from, and - yeah - good as a general habit, though in this question `Record` needs a `virtual` destructor (missing in question but as per comments/answers, and whether or not level is reached polymorphically or via `dynamic_cast`) which is non-trivial by definition.  (The "trivial" requirements are basically just hierarchical applications of "not user-provider" and "not virtual" across direct bases and non-static data members).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Changes to Record to make `level()` virtual**

You wrote:

```
Record *r = new Student();
```

After that line, the compiler considers `r` to be a pointer to either a `Record` or some `Record`-derived class (which it is), but it's only aware of the interface specified for `Record`.  There is no `virtual` `level()` function in `Record`, so you can not access `Student`'s level function through the `Record` interface.  Just add such a function to `Record` and you'll be ok:

```
virtual int level() { return 0; }  // Student may override implementation
```

or

```
virtual int level() = 0;   // Student MUST override implementation
```

**An alternative: checking whether a Record* addresses a Student**

I say above...

> There is no `virtual` `level()` function in `Record`, so you can not access `Student`'s level function through the `Record` interface.

...and show how you can add to the `Record` interface, but an alternative is to get access to the `Student` interface again, as in:

```
if (Student* p = dynamic_cast<Student*>(r))
    std::cout << "Level " << p->level() << '\n';
```

The first line checks whether the `Record* r` happens to be pointing to a `Student` (of course in your code it always is, but imagine you were inside a function that accepted a `Record*`, or were looping over a container of such pointers where some were really `Student`s and others not).  If so the returned pointer can be used to access it as `Student` object, with any extra functionality/members available (and potentially restrictions, if some `Record` functionality's hidden in some way).

This approach is generally frowned upon, as it begs the question "why were we treating the `Student` as a `Record` if we needed to know "level" and other `Record`-derived types don't even have a concept of level?".  Still, stuff like that happens sometimes.  Adding a `virtual` `level` function to `Record` isn't ideal either if `Student` is (one of) the only derived-class(es) where it would have a meaningful value: that's what's called a fat interface - you'll find a few discussions of them in The C++ Programming Language if you have a copy.

(sasha.sochka's answer was the first to mention the `dynamic_cast` option - please upvote)

**Base class should have virtual destructor**

As per chris's comment, you should add to `Record`:

```
virtual ~Record() { }
```

This ensures a derived class's destructor implementation is called when a derived object is `delete`d using a base-class pointer (for example, if you add a `delete r;` at the bottom of `main()`).  (The compiler will still ensure the base class destructor is called afterwards).

It's Undefined Behaviour if you don't do this, and at best you'll find any additional data members added in derived classes don't have their data members called... for an `int` that's harmless, but for say `std::string` it could leak memory, or even hold a lock such that the program later hangs.  Of course, it's not a good idea to rely on the best-case Undefined Behaviour ;-) but I think it's useful to understand what's definitely not happening unless you make the base destructor `virtual`.

**Recommended small improvements in Student**

If you make `level` `virtual` in `Record`, then to make it clearer to readers of the `Student` class that `level()` is an implementation of a `virtual` function from a base class, you can use the `override` keyword if you have a suitably C++11-capable compiler:

```
int level() override
{
    return level_;
}
```

This will give you a compiler error if it can't find a matching (non-`const`) `virtual int level()` in a base class, so it can avoid some occasional troubleshooting.  You may also repeat the `virtual` keyword if you feel it has documentation value (particularly nice for C++03 where `override`'s not an option), but it doesn't make any functional difference - the function stays `virtual` as long as it's (implicitly or explicitly) an override of a virtual function from a base class.

Comment: Good answer, but I think author want to use `Student * r = new Student()` here, because `level()` method is specific for `Student` and can be useless for another `Record` subclasses

Comment: @Tony, thanks for explanation,  that means, the derived class functions can not be invoked unless it is specified in the base class in the given scenario right ?

Comment: @Whoami: as long as you're treating the object as a `Record`, yes.  I'll add a section addressing how to check whether a `Record*` happens to be pointing at a `Student`, so you can access a `level()` function even though it's not exposed through the base-class interface.  That technique's considered hackish though... best avoided where possible, but it's also hackish to have what's called a "fat" interface where the base class includes virtual functions that only a subset of derived classes have meaningful implmeentations for (a do-nothing implementation may still be meaningful). Will explain.

Comment: @SpongeBobFan: could be - I've added some discussion for that scenario... cheers.

Comment: +1 for the checked use of `dynamic_cast` (and i really think that `dynamic_cast` is the most sensible answer here; adding a `level` method to the `Record` seems lika a bad idea, as intuitively i would have said that the `level` is one of the things that distinguishes the generic `Record` from a `Student`)

Comment: @umläute: could well be - so hard to know when seeing only a small part of the scenario - for example, `Record` might not be a generic Record but a shortened name for an academic record, with derived types being `Student` and `Alumnus` - both wanting "level" as in the year of study that the record describes, or the `level` in the building that their transcript's kept on, or whatever `level` is meant to mean.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot call `r->level()` because you are trying to call a function which doesn't exist in class Record. In your specific case data pointed by `r` is not only `Record` but a `Student` in the same time, so you can choose either:

```
Student *r = new Student();
cout <<"tuype " << r->getType();
cout <<"Class " << r->level()
```

or

```
Record *r = new Student();
cout <<"tuype " << r->getType();
cout <<"Class " << dynamic_cast<Student*>(r)->level()
```

If you want all `Record`s to have a level you can add pure virtual function without implementation. But if you do that you will be unable to create instantate objects of class `Record` (but you can instatntiate it's children classes):

```
class Record { ...
   virtual int level() = 0;
}
```

Another problem: you should mark your destructor in `Record` class as virtual, because when you will `delete r` constructor of `Student` will not be called

Comment: For the top "can choose either:" code, did you mean for `Record *r = new Student();` to become `Student* r = new Student();`?  As is it's still broken.  +1 for the point about potentially using `dynamic_cast<>`.

Answer (score 2):

Because the `Record` class knows nothing about a function called `level()`

You need to make a virtual `level()` function in the base class.

Answer (score 2):

Make virtual function in base class like

```
virtual int level() = 0;
```

Once you create virtual function `level()` in base class Record, it becomes necessary for student to have it's function `level()` in student class. Currently you don't have virtual  `level()` function in class Record, because of this you cannot access Student class's `level()` function using base class Record as you are doing currently.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing virtual method level() declaration in Record. On a side note, to prevent resources leak you would want to define virtual destructor in Record.

```
class Record
{
...
public:
  virtual ~Record() {}
  virtual int level() = 0;
  virtual int getType() = 0;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

student instance is upcasted to Record by:

```
Record *r = new Student();
```

While hold a Student instance, r behalf as Record. The r->getType() function call is binded to student::getType with C++'s Polymorphism machanism.
To call level() function, you can:

```
1. Add a virtual function level() to Record class.
2. downcasting r to Student class, as follows:
```

```
Student *r_new = dynamic_cast<Student>(r); 
r_new->level();
```

Answer (score 0):

When compiling, you should get an error message similar to:

```
error C2039: 'level' : is not a member of 'Record'
```

You need to add this in your Record class:

```
virtual int level()=0;
```